# Regular expression that match language codes in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, regular-expression

There is a similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676420/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-culture-names), but it does not work with bash.

What is needed to make it work with bash, to use with scripts/variables?

I'm talking about the ISO 639-1 or ISO 639-2 codes.

My bash is GNU 4.3.

Example:

```
root@box ~/test2 # ls
eng  en-US  por pt-BR
```

The regex in that pages fails:

```
root@box ~/test2 # ls | grep ^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$
root@box ~/test2 # ls | grep ^[A-Za-z]{1,8}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})*$
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@box ~/test2 # ls | grep ^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})*
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@box ~/test2 # ls | grep "^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})*"
```

Comment: Can you show the actual script you tried and which didn't work?

Comment: The expression in that answer works just fine with grep, as your comment there suggests you wanted, but here you've said you want it in Bash. Which is it?

Comment: @Freedo, [edit] your question to show the script you've tried.

Comment: How can I build a script based on this if I don't even have the regex yet? I'm just literally doing `ls | grep "their regex"`. And none in that page worked for me. You must be doing something different?

Comment: You just need to quote the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{n}` without backslashes is part of extended regular expressions, so you need the `-E` flag for grep. Also, you want to quote the regex, since as you saw, the parenthesis and braces have special meaning to the shell.

```
$ ls
eng  en-US  por  pt-BR

$ printf "%s\n" * | grep -E '^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$'
en-US
pt-BR

$ printf "%s\n" * | grep -E '^[A-Za-z]{1,8}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})*$'
eng
en-US
por
pt-BR
```

Or with just Bash:

```
$ for f in * ; do 
   [[ $f =~ ^[A-Za-z]{1,8}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})*$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "$f" ; done
eng
en-US
por
pt-BR
```

(The `[[ .. ]]` test construct is special, the braces and parenthesis have a different meaning inside it, and in fact the regex must be *unquoted* here. Note that this is totally different from `[ .. ]`. See e.g. [BashGuide on conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29))

---

The `[a-zA-Z]{1,8}` part matches strings of up to eight letters, and the final `*` allows an arbitrary number of repetitions of the group in parenthesis, so this would match something like `foobar-foobar-foobar` too.

We could change the pattern to `^[A-Za-z]{2,3}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,3})?$` only allow codes with two or three letters and just one tailing `-xx` part, if that's all you need.

---

Unquoted `{1,8}` is [brace expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion):

```
$ echo ^[A-Za-z]{1,8}
^[A-Za-z]1 ^[A-Za-z]8
```

and unquoted `[]` is a [filename pattern match (glob)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns)...

```
$ touch "^a1" "^b8"
$ echo ^[A-Za-z]{1,8}
^a1 ^b8
```

Comment: You are 3 seconds faster than me! Respect!

Comment: Wow so much different ways to do it, thanks guys...I'm so dumb, whenever I ask something here I feel so dumb afterwards because you make seems so easy. Don't even know what one to accept. But thanks for both!

Comment: Also, I noticed that matching things like `por` and `eng` result in a lot of false positives. I assume this is not something easy to be fixed, so I'll try to just use the 4 letter language codes.

Comment: @Freedo, depends on what the other files are. You can modify the numbers in `[a-z]{1,8}`, they set the number of letters that part of the expression matches.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to quote the `regex` as per grep requirements using `grep 'regex'`

Then either you will use extended regex support in grep using `egrep` or `grep -E` and this will work ok:

```
$ ls | egrep '^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$'
```

or you can use classic grep - basic regex but you need to escape `{` and `}`:

```
$ ls | grep '^[a-z]\{2\}-[A-Z]\{2\}$'
```

For these data as per your question

```
$ ls
eng
en-US
main.sh
por
pt-BR
```

Output in both grep cases will be

```
en-US
pt-BR
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a extended regular expression, so use `-E`
2. If you use search pattern with special chars, quote them

`grep -E "^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$"`